# SQL Server : MERGE  instead of Update

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge, updates

I'm attempting to do an update on a table, which is read-only. I received an error message regarding the use of merge only. Most of the examples online of using merge with a select into, etc. though. I'm looking for the simplest update statement replacement - I don't need to merge an entire table, etc.

```
update table1 set value = 'asdf' where id = 100`
```

Is the only way to use a merge in this case to create a temp table w/ my 'asdf' value and merge that into my target table?

Another solution might involve removing the read-only attribute for my transaction. I don't know how to do this though.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: What do you mean by a read only table? It is on a read only file group? If so merge won't help. Please give the exact error message.

Comment: Table '[dbo].[Settings]' into which you are trying to insert, update, or delete data has been marked as read-only. Only the merge process can perform these operations.

Comment: Ah sounds like the table you are trying to update is the target of replication.

Comment: @MartinSmith, is there a way to override this limitation for a transaction?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not at all knowledgeable about replication. I've flagged for migration to [dba.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem starts here:

> I'm attempting to do an update on a table, which is read-only.

Whether it's a replicated table or simply set as read only (which admins or admin-level users can set), you won't be able to update the table.

You can select the data from that table into a another table and try your update there.

```
SELECT *
INTO TempTable1
FROM table1


update TempTable1 
set value = 'asdf' 
where id = 100`
```

You will need appropriate permissions to be able to manipulate (create, insert, update or delete) any object.

Comment: As with anything in IT, "read-only" is relative. The issue I'm running into isn't that this table is set to read-only, and do not have permissions to change it. The issue is that the read-only property on this table is set to False, yet I get a read-only error message. I'm assuming this has something to do with replication services being used. However, I don't know much about replication or how it effects a user's ability to write to a table.